# Reloading TableView Data after pop From DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I reload my tableView data after I click back button/pop from my `detailViewController` (using `UINavigationController` and push)? I tried reloading my tableView in `viewDidAppear` but nothing has changed. Below I attached my storyboard so that you guys can have a idea about what my problem is. When I click save, I want all the data to be automatically reloaded to my tableView when I go back to my `UITableViewController`. How can I achieve this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1YyV.png

Below is my code for saving new data to coreData using saveButton.

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    CoreDataAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSString *name = self.nameTextfield.text;
    NSString *phoneNumber = self.phoneTextfield.text;

    CoreDataTableViewController *cdtvc = [[CoreDataTableViewController alloc] init];

    [newContact setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    [cdtvc.name addObject:name];
    [newContact setValue:phoneNumber forKey:@"phone"];
    [cdtvc.phone addObject:phoneNumber];

    NSError *error;
   [context save:&error];
   [cdtvc.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Could you paste some code in wich you fill and reload your data? Where do you store your data ? CoreData ?

Comment: Yes I'm using coredata. I tried to reload my tableview on viewDidAppear but it just don't work.

Comment: Are you using a fetched results controller or is the data loaded/stored manually in `cdtvc`?

Comment: i'm using fetched result controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reloading the `tableView` of another instance of your `CoreDataTableViewController`. With this line:

> ```
> CoreDataTableViewController *cdtvc = [[CoreDataTableViewController alloc] init];
> ```

you create a new `CoreDataTableViewController` instance but when you pop the current view controller from the navigation stack another instance will be visible whose table view has not received the message `-reloadData`.

To fix this replace the above line with this code:

```
NSArray *navigationStack = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSInteger previousViewControllerIndex = navigationStack.count - 2;
CoreDataTableViewController *cdtvc = [navigationStack objectAtIndex:previousViewControllerIndex];
```

and see if it does the trick. (Now cdtv is a reference to the *original* view controller on the navigation stack.)